# How to print out the top-level json after modification of descendants

Tags: json, windows, cmd, edit, jq

Hello i managed to create this jq filter `.profiles | recurse | .gameDir? |  if type == "null" then "" else . end | scan("{REPLACE}.*") | sub("{REPLACE}"; "{REPLACESTRINGHERE}")`. it succesfully replaces what i want (checked at jqplay.org) but now i'd like to print the full json and not just the modified strings

Comment: Please provide a mcve - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @peak what? i'm just asking what do i have to add to that jq filter (or cmd line args to jq) so that the output will be the full json file

Comment: Have you read stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapting your query:

```
.profiles |= walk( if type == "object" and has("gameDir")
                   then .gameDir |=
                     (if type == "null" then "" else . end
                     | scan("{REPLACE}.*") | sub("{REPLACE}"; "{REPLACESTRINGHERE}"))
                   else . 
                   end )
```

(This can easily be tweaked for greater efficiency.)

If your jq does not have `walk`, you can google it (jq “def walk”) or snarf its def from the jq FAQ https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ

#### walk-free approach

For the record, here's an illustration of a walk-free approach using `paths`.  The following also makes some changes in the computation of the replacement string -- notably it eliminates the use of `scan` -- so it is not logically equivalent, but is likely to be more useful as well as more efficient.

```
.profiles |= 
   ( . as $in
   | reduce (paths | select(.[-1] == "gameDir")) as $path ($in;
       ($in | getpath($path)
        | if type == "null" then ""
              else sub(".*{REPLACE}"; "{REPLACESTRINGHERE}")
              end) as $value
       | setpath($path; $value) ))
```

Comment: Note use of |= twice.

Comment: hey i can't get this to work. how do i import that walk function?